# Clearing an obd 1 check engine light

Tags: ford, f-150, obd-i

I have a 1994 F-150 that threw a check engine light for my evap canister. I replaced the part and adjacent vacuum hose but I can't get the code to reset. My scanner does not have a code reset button and I've tried both disconnecting the negative battery terminal for a few hours and pulling the ECU fuse but neither have had any effect. Can someone tell me how to reset it please? Thank you

Comment: The question I have for you is, are you sure you've cured the problem? Not sure what else could be going on, but if the problem still exists, you won't ever get the code to clear. Just a thought.

Comment: what is the code that your device detects?

Comment: I guess it decided to reset itself at some point last night, now I have a totally new code. Thanks for the replies